# "IndexError: list index out of range" in very simple 3 lines of Python code

Tags: python-3.x, list, index-error

I am a newbie to the programming and trying to understand how things work.
I couldn't get my program to iterate through numpy.array normally, so I decided to try one level simple iteration through list. But still it wouldn't work!
The code is as follows:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in my_list:
    print(my_list[i])
```

[The output is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BBcq.png)

So it doesn't take the `my_list[0]` index of some reason and comes out of range.
Could you please help me to understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do. When you iterate over an iterable like a list with

```
for i in my_list:
```

each `i` is each member of the list, *not* the index of the member of the list. So, in your case, if you want to print each member of the list, use

```
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

Think about it: what if the 3rd member of the list was `9`, for example? Your code would be trying to print `my_list[9]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out that's not how you should iterate over the elements of the list.

But if you persist, your loop be should over the `range(my_list)`, at the moment you're indexing by the values of the list, and since the length is 7, the last valid index is 6, not 7.

Comment: Thank you! I understood my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You get an IndexError, because you are looping through the values, which means, that your first value for i is 1 and the last one is 7. Because 7 is an invalid Index for this list you get an IndexError. A suitable code would be:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now :)